# Composer PSR4 auto-loading not working on project clone

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a project working and I have simply cloned the repo and run `composer install` and then `composer dumpautoload -o` but the project can not see my classes.

compose.json

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4":{
            "App\\": "app",
            "Framework\\" : "framework"
        },
        "files": [
            "helpers/global.php"
        ]
    },

...
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ .'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$container = new League\Container\Container;

// Auto wiring, container will load type hinted dependencies into controllers
$container->delegate(new \League\Container\ReflectionContainer());

// Get the config provider so we can get all the other providers from the config
$container->addServiceProvider(new \App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider());
```

This is where the code fails with:

```
Class 'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider' not found
```

configserviceprovider.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Framework\Config\Config;
use Framework\Config\Loaders\ArrayLoader;
use League\Container\ServiceProvider\AbstractServiceProvider;

class ConfigServiceProvider extends AbstractServiceProvider
{

    protected $provides = [
        'config'
    ];

    public function register()
    {

        $this->getContainer()->share('config', function(){

            $loader = new ArrayLoader([
                'app' => base_path('config/app.php'),
                'cache' => base_path('config/cache.php')
            ]);

            return (new Config)->load([$loader]);

        });

    }

}
```

My folder structure is like so:

- app

  - Controllers
  - Providers

    - ConfigServiceProvider.php
  - Views
- public

  - index.php

This code all works on another project so I guess I'm missing a command to make composer see these classes?

Comment: Move ConfigServiceProvider into the Providers directory and try again.

Comment: If the suggestion from @Pete doesn't help, and the content of `ConfigServiceProvider.php` is verbatim, you will also need to add `<?php` to the start of the file.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the question with your edit. Now I'm not sure if the `-o` argument to `composer dump-autoload` was intentional, but that makes Composer generate a classmap (an array of classes mapped to filenames), which is cumbersome to use in development environments. With `-o` you will have to run the Composer command every time you create a class. Try running just `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @Pete "*With -o you will have to run the Composer command every time you create a class*" - this is not true, only changing namespaces structure can create issues with optimized autoloader. Although it does not make much sense in dev environment, it does not create any problem in most cases either.